# How to read the value in input buffer of serial port in java

Tags: java, serial-port, buffer

I need to read the value in input buffer of serial port in java at present in C# in system.io.ports.serialport we have have readline() function which does the following task

```
    // Summary:
    //     Reads up to the System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.NewLine value in the input buffer.        
    //
    // Returns:
    //     The contents of the input buffer up to the first occurrence of a
    //     System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.NewLine value. 
    // Exceptions:
    //   System.InvalidOperationException:
    //     The specified port is not open.
    //
    //   System.TimeoutException:
    //     The operation did not complete before the time-out period ended.- or -No bytes were read.
```

So now what is the equivalent function in java to do this task.Please help me to resolve.

Comment: is this Java question or C# question? please make your mind

Comment: this is java question

Comment: please get rid of c# tag